i cant find windows security(virus protection) to enable realtime protection - but appstore has microsoft defender, it requires some payment
i installed win11, from iso, did not pay, managed to activate and updated it. Its all updated and fresh.
However windows security is nonexistent:

going to the msft app store - there is only some microsoft defender which requires some paid subsccription(this is probably some other app):

i tried to get the pckg via cli in powershell as admin:
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage

but it brings no result.
i dont get where to find normal standard windows security

Due to the fact you pirated Windows. Microsoft Defender was removed. You will have to reinstall Windows using a legitimate non-modified Windows image. This will mean you will need to purchase a license to Windows.

You can’t reset an application that isn’t installed and you can’t install Windows defender since you pirated Windows

That app could be different, but here is the link of Security app you can try to install https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9p6pmztm93lr?hl=en-US&gl=US.

If this doesn't work, and assuming you used the original ISO, I suggest repairing your Windows installation.
Go to Settings > System > Recovery > click on the Reset PC option or Reinstall Windows. If anything was missed during first installation, this should help to resolve it. You can choose to keep existing files, but apps will need to be installed again.

Let me know if any of them worked.

thx; i do have it installed, - its paid app, not the standard windows system component that i need; its this microsoft defender that needs subscription!

Microsoft Defender cannot be subscribed to.
